# Micronaut DI does not work with Graal Native Image built in Maven

Tags: java, docker, maven, micronaut, graalvm

I have a minimal app on Micronaut it looks like this:

```
@Introspected
public class BookRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<Book, BookSaved> {

    @Inject
    private BookService service;

    @Override
    public BookSaved execute(Book input) {
        return service.process(input);
    }

}

@Singleton
@Introspected
public class BookService {

  public BookSaved process(Book input) {
    BookSaved bookSaved = new BookSaved();
    bookSaved.setName(input.getName());
    bookSaved.setIsbn(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return bookSaved;
  }

}
```

- Runtime and DTO classes.

My project successfully builds and runs on Graal Native Image using a plugin from Micronaut - ./mvnm

But I am trying to use native-image to build directly through Docker container. And the image is going! But if I try to call the lambda, I get an error that the field for dependency injection was not found :( This file is remade from Micronaut's Gradle version:

```
# STEP 1: Packaging project .jar in Docker image 'builder'
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 as build

COPY . /home/application
WORKDIR /home/application

RUN mvn clean package

# STEP 2: Downloading Graal and C libraries in Docker image 'graalvm'
FROM amazonlinux:2018.03 as graal

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV JDK_VERSION java8
ENV GRAAL_VERSION 21.0.0.2
ENV GRAAL_FILENAME graalvm-ce-${JDK_VERSION}-linux-amd64-${GRAAL_VERSION}.tar.gz

RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ libc6-dev zlib1g-dev curl bash zlib zlib-devel zip
RUN curl -4 -L https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-${GRAAL_VERSION}/${GRAAL_FILENAME} -o /tmp/${GRAAL_FILENAME}
RUN tar -zxvf /tmp/${GRAAL_FILENAME} -C /tmp
RUN mv /tmp/graalvm-ce-${JDK_VERSION}-${GRAAL_VERSION} /usr/lib/graalvm
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*

CMD ["/usr/lib/graalvm/bin/native-image"]

# STEP 3: Building and zipping a Native Image with bootstrap file
FROM graal

COPY --from=build /home/application/ /home/application/
WORKDIR /home/application

RUN /usr/lib/graalvm/bin/gu install native-image
RUN /usr/lib/graalvm/bin/native-image --no-fallback --no-server -jar target/MicronautGraal-0.1.jar -H:Name=micronaut-graal -H:Class=com.example.BookLambdaRuntime
RUN chmod 777 bootstrap
RUN chmod 777 micronaut-graal
RUN zip -j micronaut-graal.zip bootstrap micronaut-graal

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/application/complete"]
```

The error itself:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for field [service] of class: com.example.BookRequestHandler
Message: Error setting field value: No field 'service' found for type: com.example.BookRequestHandler
```

I'm sure the problem is not in the code, as it will run and work through the ./mvnm plugin. Am I missing something in the app build? My image through the plugin is 500kb more than through native-image directly.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away after adding the annotation processor path - graal, and explicitly declaring validation and inject in the inheritor:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
  <path>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
  </path>
  <path>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
  </path>
  <path>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
  </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a JVM limitation that we cannot inject private fields without using reflection.

You have 2 options:

1. Make the field package private instead of private
2. Add `@ReflectiveAccess` onto the field to generate the necessary graal reflective metadata

Answer (score 0):

Use should consider making injection through constructor, that is recommended way for GraalVM native applications.

```
@Introspected
public class BookRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<Book, BookSaved> {

    private final BookService service;

    @Inject
    public BookRequestHandler(BookService service) {
      this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public BookSaved execute(Book input) {
        return service.process(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to the way Micronaut initializes MicronautRequestHandler instances, constructor injection does not work. Your entry point class, which extends AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime, creates an instance of your request handler and obtains the application context through that (see the empty constructor of MicronautRequestHandler).

Comment: Although this may not work in the context of MicronautRequestHandler, FWIW I had a similar issue (in a different service class), and changing to constructor injection solved the problem for me.